# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar un dropdown que se encuentra en un Modal en Bootstrap 4.1.0 en Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, bootstrap-4

Buenas y saludos a la comunidad

Tengo un inconveniente en un dropdown que se encuentra en un Modal no despliega lo que contiene adjunto imagen y codigo si alguien con mas conocimientos me puede apoyar gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EN el JSP.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@include file="/template/header.jsp"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="${path}/css/bootstrap.min.css">

            <script  type="text/javascript"  src="${path}/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script    type="text/javascript"  src="${path}/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>          
            <script   type="text/javascript" src="${path}/js/popper.min.js"></script>  
            <script   type="text/javascript" src="${path}/js/main.js"></script>  
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<br>
<br>
 <div class="container">
 <div class="myForm">

 <a href="${path}/direccion/form" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar direccion</a>
 <br>
 <br>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@getbootstrap">Agregar Direccion</button>

    <form method="post" action="${path}/direccion/agregar">
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Actualizar o Guardar</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Pais:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Ciudad:</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
                  </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Distrito:</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
                  </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Usuario:</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
                  </div>

                    <div class="btn-group dropdown">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >Dropdown</button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a> 
                         <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a> 

                    </div>
                </div>


              </div>
             <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
        </form>
      </div>    


 <br>



 <br>
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Ciudad</th>
                <th>Distrito</th>
                <th>Pais</th>
                <th>Usuario</th>
                <th>Actualizar</th>
                <th>Eliminar</th>   
            </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${direcciones}" var="direccion">
                <tr>
                    <td>${direccion.ciudad}</td>
                    <td>${direccion.distrito}</td>
                    <td>${direccion.pais}</td>
                    <td>${direccion.usuario.usuarioNombre}</td>
                    <td><a href="${path}/direccion/actualizar/${direccion.id}">Actualizar</a></td>
                    <td><a href="${path}/direccion/eliminar/${direccion.id}">Eliminar</a></td>
                </tr>

            </c:forEach>

        </tbody>



    </table>
    </div>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: El dropdown se despliega bien. Revisa tus css y js. Limpia el cache del navegador. Con los proyectos de spring suelo tener problemas por que las hojas se guardan en el cache y no se reflejan los cambios. No parece problema de Spring

Comment: uhmm no resulta cuando agrego estas lineas me funciona pero yo quiero css y js esten alojados localmente <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: Si ya vi cual fue el error fue en mi header.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Esto es en mi caso en mi header.jsp

Insert title here

```
        <script  type="text/javascript"  src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script    type="text/javascript"  src="${path}/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>          
        <script   type="text/javascript" src="${path}/js/popper.min.js"></script>
```

y esto es en lista.jsp

<%@include file="/template/header.jsp"%>

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="${path}/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script  type="text/javascript"  src="${path}/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script    type="text/javascript"  src="${path}/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>          
        <script   type="text/javascript" src="${path}/js/popper.min.js"></script>  
        <script   type="text/javascript" src="${path}/js/main.js"></script>
```

Insert title here